# Azure Service Fabric - Multiple application deployment through Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have a two microservices applications running in Azure Service fabric cluster. I don't have any issue when I deploy the applications from Visual Studio. But when I try to deploy the applications through Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline I'm getting the below error.

**[error]Found more than one item with search pattern D:\a\r1\a**\drop\projectartifacts**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml. There can be only one.**

From this error message what I can understand I should have only one Cloud.xml file in the solution.

I would like to know the best practices to create multiple applications in Azure Service Fabric cluster and how to resolve the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could create 2 separate solution files and target those from AzureDevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two SF applications in the solution. If you are building both and dropping then on the same folder, you will have two cloud.xml files.

Because you specified a broad search pattern, it will find both.

You didn't tell which task is throwing this exception, I will assume it is the Deploy Service Fabric Application.

To deploy both applications, you should have two steps, one pointing to each application, then you should fix the search pattern to be more specific on which SF App you are deploying.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you are right. I'm getting this error while executing Deploy Service Fabric Application task. I will try what you have suggested.