# Azure Pipelines - CI/CD: How to execute all .sql files in a folder against DB

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, sql-function

I have all the SQL files checked into a repo on Azure devops. 
I have naming convention that allows me to know which .sql files are used by other .sql files (ex. file creates a view that is used by a stored procedure). 
I am wanting to force the use of the repo for tracking code changes, and would prefer not to use dacpac file. I want each function / view / stored procedure to have it's own file.

My question, how would I execute all .sql files matching '**..\Functions\BASE_*.sql**' against a database from an azure pipeline? I tried the below, but does not support multiple files being matched. Is there a better option that does? Do I need to script a loop and do it myself?

```
# pipeline

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    TaskType: 'sqlQuery'
    SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Functions\BASE_*.sql'
    ServerName: '$(SQL_ServerName).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: '$(SQL_DatabaseName)'
    AuthScheme: 'sqlServerAuthentication'
    SqlUsername: '$(SQL_UserName)'
    SqlPassword: '$(SQL_Password)'
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Starting: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup
==============================================================================
Task         : SQL Server database deploy
Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
Version      : 0.3.23
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
==============================================================================
##[error]Found more than one file to deploy with search pattern d:\a\1\s\Functions\BASE_*.sql. There can be only one.
Finishing: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a day's research and trial, the best I could come up with was to keep files separate in the repo, but then combine multiple files together in the CI/CD pipeline before running it against the DB.

I created a template to combine matching files into a single file in the staging directory, publish it for debugging the pipeline, then execute it against the SQL server.

The template is:

```
# Template for executing all SQL files matching a string search

parameters:
- name: path #$path = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Functions"
  type: string
- name: match #$match = "BASE_*.sql"
  type: string
- name: outPath #$outPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Functions"
  type: string
- name: outName #$outName = "BASE.sql"
  type: string

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo Source Files:
      Get-ChildItem ${{parameters.path}} -include ${{parameters.match}} -rec 
  displayName: 'Files to process: ${{parameters.match}}'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo Creating: ${{parameters.outPath}}\${{parameters.outName}}
      Get-ChildItem ${{parameters.path}} -include ${{parameters.match}} -rec | ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} | out-file ${{parameters.outPath}}\${{parameters.outName}}
  displayName: 'Combine: ${{parameters.outName}}'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
   targetPath: '${{parameters.outPath}}\${{parameters.outName}}'
   artifact: '${{parameters.outName}}'
   publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  displayName: 'Publish: ${{parameters.outName}}'
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    TaskType: 'sqlQuery'
    SqlFile: '${{parameters.outPath}}\${{parameters.outName}}'
    ServerName: '$(SQL_ServerName).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: '$(SQL_DatabaseName)'
    AuthScheme: 'sqlServerAuthentication'
    SqlUsername: '$(SQL_UserName)'
    SqlPassword: '$(SQL_Password)'
  displayName: 'Create or Alter: ${{parameters.outName}}'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Remove-Item ${{parameters.path}}\${{parameters.match}} -Recurse
  displayName: 'Delete Files: ${{parameters.match}}'
```

The main pipeline then calls the template with the different search strings.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: MKDIR "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\Combined\\Functions"
  displayName: 'Create Output Folder'
- template: azTemplate/CombineAndRunSQLFiles.yml # Functions: UTIL
  parameters:
    path: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\Functions"
    match: "UTIL_*.sql"
    outPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\Combined\\Functions"
    outName: "UTIL.sql"
- template: azTemplate/CombineAndRunSQLFiles.yml # Functions: BASE
  parameters:
    path: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\Functions"
    match: "BASE_*.sql"
    outPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\Combined\\Functions"
    outName: "BASE.sql"
```

Result:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: windows-latest
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Today at 9:55 AM
Duration: 1m 6s

Job preparation parameters
5 artifacts produced
Job live console data:
Finishing: Job
```

Comment: Hi michael, would you minding accepting it as answer since you've added useful workaround here? Check [can I answer my self-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and how to [accept own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late reaction, but when you find this Post and you do not want to combine your sql files into one file, you can loop over files in Powershell.

To do so, create a Powershell script file, e.g. 'runsql.ps1' and add it to your Repo. In it, loop over files and call Invoke-Sqlcmd:

```
# Input parameters
param (
    [string]$ServerInstance,
    [string]$Database,
    [string]$Folder,
    [string]$Filter
)

# Get a list of all .sql files in the folder with the give filter
$SqlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter $Filter

# Loop through each .sql file
foreach ($SqlFile in $SqlFiles) {
    $ScriptPath = Join-Path $Folder $SqlFile
    echo "Invoke-Sqlcmd $ScriptPath"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -QueryTimeout 0 -InputFile $ScriptPath -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

This sample uses Windows Authentication (my Pipeline agent runs with an identity that is also db owner in the MSSQL db) but username/password works just as well I guess.

I added an 'echo' line to see what scripts were run in the DevOps job log.
The '-ErrorAction Stop' argument causes the Powershell task to fail on an sql error, so the Pipeline job is flagged as failed

Now add a task to your Pipeline to run this Powershell script.
Don't forget to define your serverInstance, database and scriptFolder under variables.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'runsql.ps1'
    arguments: '-ServerInstance "$(serverInstance)" -Database "$(database)" -Folder "$(scriptFolder)" -Filter "*.sql"'
```

Answer (score -1):

> How would I execute all .sql files matching
> '..\Functions\BASE_*.sql' against a database from an azure pipeline? I
> tried the below, but does not support multiple files being matched. Is
> there a better option that does? Do I need to script a loop and do it
> myself?

If you want to execute several sql files, you need to have several corresponding `WinRM SQL Server DB Deployment` tasks/steps. This task is by design to deploy one `.dacpac` or `.sql` file at a time, it doesn't support deploy multiple scripts.

According to *I want each function / view / stored procedure to have it's own file*. So if you have three scripts for `function/view/stored procedure`, then you need at least three `SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0` steps in your pipeline. Check similar issues here([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35449773/10910450),[#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976342/10910450)). There's no better option and you have to run this task several times for your different scripts.